# String splitting with a special structure

Tags: c#, split

I have strings of the following form:

str = "[int]:[int],[int]:[int],[int]:[int],[int]:[int], ..." (for undefined number of times).

What I did was this:

```
string[] str_split = str.Split(','); 
for( int i = 0; i < str_split.Length; i++ )
{ 
    string[] str_split2 = str_split[i].Split(':'); 
}
```

Unfortunately this breaks when some of the numbers have extra ',' inside a number. For example, we have something like this:

695,000:14,306,000:12,136000:12,363000:6

in which the followings are the numbers, ordered from the left to the right:

695,000

14

306,000

12

136000

12

363000

6

How can I resolve this string splitting problem?

Comment: Will it always be the number to the left of the `:` who has the commas? If not, there's no reliable way of performing the split. For example, `123,456,789` may be interpreted as either `123,456`, `789`, or as `123`, `456,789`.

Comment: If I correctly understand you: No, some of the numbers might have extra commas, and some may not have.

Comment: I meant: Can you have cases like `123:456,789`, where the number to the right of the `:`, `456,789`, contains a comma?

Comment: as I can see you don't have a logically conclusive formatting in the first place, as Douglas mentioned, what if there is both a comma separator and right after it first decimal number with a comma, how could you tell which way to go (unless you always have 'dots' but as I can see you don't)

Answer (score 1):

If it is the case that only the number to the left of the colon separator can contain commas, then you could simply express this as:

```
string s = "695,000:14,306,000:12,136000:12,363000:6";
var parts = Regex.Split(s, @":|(?<=:\d+),");
```

The regex pattern, which identifies the separators, reads: "any colon, or any comma that follows a colon and a sequence of digits (but not another comma)".

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is split using : as delimiter. The resultant array will have numbers of the format [int],[int]. Parse through the array and split each entry using , as the delimiter. This will give you an array of [int] numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best way to do it and it might not work all the time but here's what I'd do.

```
string[] leftRightDoubles = str.Split(':'); 
foreach(string substring in leftRightDoubles){
  string[] indivNumbers = str.Split(',');
  //if indivNumbers.Length == 2, you know that these two are separate numbers
  //if indivNumbers.Length > 2, use heuristics to determine which parts belong to which number
  if(indivNumbers.Length > 2) {
    for(int i = 0, i < indivNumbers.Length, i++) {
      if(indivNumbers[i] != '000') { //Or use some other heuristic
        //It's a new number
      } else {
        //It's the rest of previous number
      }
    }
  }
}
```

//It's sort of pseudocode with comments (haven't touched C# in a while so I don't want to write full C# code)